# Replacing letters using a dictionary

Tags: python

I had a text that I separated into individual sounds by means of graphemes. These graphemes are now part of a list, as can be seen below:

```
graphemes = ["th", "e", "g", "i", "r", "l", "th", "a", "t", "r", "ea", "d", "s", ...]
```

In addition to that, I also have a dictionary which links some of those graphemes to a number:

```
graph_nums = {"th":1, "s":2, "t":3, ...}
```

Finally, I have a set of conditions. For example, "if -s comes after a vowel" or "if -t comes before a consonant".

What I want to do is iterate over the list of graphemes and, if one of the conditions is met, then replace the grapheme with its corresponding number.

This is what I tried to do so far:

```
special_graphemes = ["s", "t"...] #a list with the characters that are mentioned in the conditions
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", ...] #a list with all the vowels and dipthongs 
consonants = ["b", "c", "d", ...] #a list of all consonants and groups of consonants
output = ""

for grapheme in graphemes: #iterate over each grapheme
    if grapheme in special_graphemes: #if the grapheme is one of the graphemes that needs to be replaced by a number
        if graphemes[grapheme-1] in vowels: #for a condition like "if -s comes after a vowel", it needs to be checked whether the previous grapheme is a vowel
            output += graph_nums.get(num) #if the previous condition applies, then replace the grapheme by its number, according to the dictionary
       elif XXXX #other conditions checked in a similar way
    else:
        output += grapheme #otherwise, just keep the grapheme as it is
print(output)
```

However, when I run this, I get an error concerning the indexes (i.e., this is wrong: `graphemes[grapheme-1]`). How could I then access the positions I'm interested in and replace them when necessary?

Also, I'm not sure either whether the way I'm accessing the dictionary and replacing the graphemes is correct either.

Comment: Use `for i, grapheme in enumerate(graphemes)`

Comment: @SilverSlash where should I use that? Could you please expand?

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If so you should add/mark a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Python list comprehension**

### Try this :

```
graphemes = ["th", "e", "g", "i", "r", "l", "th", "a", "t", "r", "ea", "d", "s"]
graph_nums = {"th":1, "s":2, "t":3}
out_graphemes = [ x for x in (map(graph_nums.get, graphemes, graphemes)) ]
print (out_graphemes)
```

### Output

[1, 'e', 'g', 'i', 'r', 'l', 1, 'a', 3, 'r', 'ea', 'd', 2]